# how to use date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); function value as column name in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store `date` as `column` name in `php`.

I tried below code but its giving error.

```
<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "id788089_smartcollegeapp";
    $dbpass = "smart123";

    mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("id788089_smartcollegeapp");

    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $table = trim($array_not_present_student[0]) . 
             '_' . trim($array_not_present_student[1]) . 
             '_' . trim($array_not_present_student[2]) . 
             '_' . trim($array_not_present_student[3]) . 
             '_' . trim($array_not_present_student[4]);

    $new ="ALTER TABLE " . $table . " ADD " . $date . " VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL";
    mysql_query($new)or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

**Error:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2017-03-26 04:14:51 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL' at line 1.

Comment: Obvious answer, you can't have spaces in a column name.  Obvious question... why would you want to do this.

Comment: actually i sent attendance data from my android and store in mysql with date and time . thank you !

Comment: how to can i remove spaces from this $date variable?

Comment: sahil i removed spaces from date but again its giving error:-You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2017-03-2604:36:21 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL' at line 1

Comment: You **can** have spaces in a column name. Regardless, this is a terrible idea. Whatever it is you're trying to do, there's a better solution.

Comment: so how can i insert date as column name? any suggestion

Comment: The answer is you make a table that has a column named 'attendance' that is either a DATETIME or a TIMESTAMP.  Then you use a query like this:  INSERT INTO TABLE (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below query. It worked in `MySQL`. Added `` ` `` before `$date`.

```
$new ="ALTER TABLE ".$table." ADD `".$date."` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL";
```

Comment: Then mark it as accepted. By the way `mysql` has been deprecated, start learning `mysqli` and `pdo`, also creating column name as `date` is not good idea.

Comment: again thank you for giving advice so can you give any alternative solutions for date

Comment: @kdblue Use rows instead of columns. That's what they're meant for. @ SachinPATIL Why would you help OP shoot himself in the foot??